# Lodash.js equivalent that searches for object that meets criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm currently iterating through an object array and looking for a value. I'm sure Lodash has a way of doing this, but I can't find it. Here's the code.

```
var foo = 1; // Criteria to search for
var exists = false;
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id == foo) {exists = true; break;}
};
```

Basically this just looks if any element that meets the criteria exists. Does anyone know the Lo-Dash equivalent of this?

Comment: [_.some()](https://lodash.com/docs#some)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some):

```
_.some(users, function(user) {
  return user.id === 'foo';
})
```

lo-dash also supports a shorthand form for the simple case of matching on specific attributes. Your example falls into this case:

```
_.some(users, { id: 'foo' })
```

If you do not need to support IE8 you can use the native `Array.prototype.some`:

```
users.some(function(user) {
  return user.id === 'foo';
})
```

[`Array.prototype.some` compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.some)